# plugin plugin.google.maps using phonegap build service doesnt work on ios

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

i have a small project using the plugin plugin.google.maps (https://github.com/wf9a5m75/phonegap-googlemaps-plugin) .

Also, i use phonegap buid service, not CLI.

In config.xml file i have the code

```
<gap:plugin name="plugin.google.maps" source="plugins.cordova.io" version="~1.2.4">
    <param name="API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID" value="xxx" />
    <param name="API_KEY_FOR_IOS" value="xxx" />
</gap:plugin>
```

Android apk's works like a charm, but on ios device i get the message

"Api key is not setted.
Please replace 'API_KEY_FOR_IOS' in the platforms/ios/.../...Info.plist with your API key."

Does anyone have a clue how i can solve this using the phonegap build service?

Comment: hi, sorry for add this comment here, but i'm trying to use this plugin on my phonegap build app but the phonegap-build compiler fails, you can help me with an example app using the plugin? im trying to compile on android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite the fact that this was supposed to work

(https://github.com/wf9a5m75/phonegap-googlemaps-plugin/issues/411#issuecomment-75452290)

after a couple of days in a nutshell i figured that i had to override the instructions for ios property list for the plist key "Google Maps API Key".

So, in config.xml i inserted the code:

```
<gap:config-file platform="ios" parent="Google Maps API Key" mode="replace">   
    <string>xxx</string>
</gap:config-file>
```

where xxx is the Google Maps API Key for iOS

http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/configuring_config_file_element.md.html